# Initialize final variable in constructor

Tags: java, constructor, final

I'm trying to initialize a `private final` variable in the constructor of my class. I found this thread explaining how to do it ([Initialize a static final field in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093744/initialize-a-static-final-field-in-the-constructor)), but eclipse doesn't seem to like my code. I was wondering if someone could shed some light on what I might be doing wrong.

```
public class A {
  final private String myString;

  public A() {
    myString = "content";
  }
}
```

With this code I'm getting:

> The blank final field myString may not have been initialized

This seems pretty dang similar to the examples in the thread I linked to.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: what error does eclipse give?  I cut and pasted your example into IntelliJ, and it was happy.

Comment: It gives the second code block in my post above.  I'm using 4.4.0 and Java 7  but the actual error when I run it is this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The blank final field myString may not have been initialized

 at package.<init>(A.java:31)
 at package.Test.main(Test.java:5)initialized

Comment: As an aside, I would suggest using the convention of upper-case with underscores for naming constants `LIKE_THIS`.

Comment: Does it work if you simply call `javac` on the file?  It's a longshot.

Comment: In your real code, do you have more than one constructor?  Or have you seen this problem with the exact code above.  I suspect that something is being lost in translation.

Comment: Interesting discussion here: [compile - Java "blank final field may not have been initialized"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652772/java-blank-final-field-may-not-have-been-initialized-exception-thrown-in-metho).  See also [Java the final field may not have been initialzied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599721/the-final-field-may-not-already-have-been-initialized)

Comment: @user3780616 I doubt that the code above produces this error. Please provide the full example (your class A does not have a line #31)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is perfectly valid. This is probably caused by:

1. Bad IDE settings
2. Damaged or alternative javac compiler.

Re-download your IDE, you probably want to download the latest version of it and perform a clean install. You can also try to download and install JDK again (preferably latest version).

*Just a little tip. In Java, there is a convention that variable visibility modifier comes first. So instead of final private, learn to write private final.*

Comment: Reinstalled JDK and Eclipse and everything works.  Not sure why, but hey, it works :)  Thanks for the help everybody!